# Position a menu item at the left end of the actionbar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, toolbar

How to move a menu icon to the left end of the bar, to the left of the app's name, as shows in this picture? 
Is there a way to do this by xml only, without adding java codes?

[image: move item to left]
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                                 tools:context="com.robyn.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:icon="@drawable/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:icon="@drawable/favo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:icon="@drawable/hour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.robyn.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Just dont use menu and make it an image view in the toolbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `@Martin De Simone`, if you put image inside `toolbar` tag, a small space will be left, it won't be at very left. If you are ok with this, you can do so like below,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left|start">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dehaze"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

There are more possible solutions.

1. It's kind of a hack, but if you are targeting `API` Level 17 and above, you can set `layoutDirection="rtl". *You have to set your title direction accordingly*
2. You must be using `Java` code for setting `toolbar`, add some more lines to it.

   ```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
   }
   toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_dehaze);  //your icon
   toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           //Do whatever you want to do here
       }
   });
   ```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

`layoutDirection="rtl" it's help for me